# C# Custom Chain, Add CRC bytes

Tags: c#, chain

I want to write a Method chain to add CRC ( 2 byte ) with byte[].
with internet source, I write this . but not work... 
with less knowledge,I do not know why...
Please help me..

```
public byte[] AddCrc<T>(this byte[] x)
{
    if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    int oldLen = x.Length;
    byte[] y = makeCrc2bytes(x, oldLen);
    Array.Resize<byte>(ref x, x.Length + y.Length);
    Array.Copy(y, 0, x, oldLen, y.Length);
    return x;
}
```

... Example ...

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
    buffer[0] = 0x01;
    buffer[1] = 0x02;
    buffer[2] = 0x03;
    buffer[3] = 0x04;
    buffer[4] = 0x05;
    buffer[5] = 0x06;
 byte[] buffer2 = buffer.AddCrc();  // Now work.
```

Comment: Downvoted. I accept all. I learned How to write from Matthew's. In future, I will do well.  In stackoverflow, All page is useful. I hope My poor question and great answer from Matthew will help someone : )

Answer (score 1):

You are having a compiler error since you aren't passing the unused type parameter.  Remove that from the `.AddCrc(...)` method.  BTW, the array you passed into `.AddCrc()` is by value so it is not extended.  `Array.Resize<T>(...)` creates a new array, copies the original value into that array then changes the reference passed into the function (`ref`).

You may as well do this...

```
public static byte[] AddCrc(this byte[] input) //type param not used.
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

    var crc = makeCrc2bytes(input, input.Length);

    var result = new byte[input.Length + crc.Length];
    Array.Copy(input, 0, result, 0, input.Length);
    Array.Copy(crc, 0, result, input.Length, crc.Length);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It work ! : ) thank you . Now, I understand How to write.I can write other chian method too.